# connecting to my computer via python sockets while behind a router

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007227) question to connect to my laptop from another laptop over the internet. Both laptops are behind different routers and are running Ubuntu. Here is my server side code:

```
import socket

class Server():
  def __init__(self,Adress=('',5000),MaxClient=1):
      self.s = socket.socket()
      self.s.bind(Adress)
      self.s.listen(MaxClient)
  def WaitForConnection(self):
      self.Client, self.Adr=(self.s.accept())
      print('Got a connection from: '+str(self.Client)+'.')


s = Server()
s.WaitForConnection()
```

and client side code:

```
import socket

class Client():
    myIP = "123.456.789.123" # I got my real IP by running "curl https://ipinfo.io/ip"
    def __init__(self,Adress=(myIP,5000)):
        self.s = socket.socket()
        self.s.connect(Adress)

c = Client()
```

I started up server.py on the 'server laptop' by running `python3 server.py` and then ran `python3 client.py` on the 'client laptop' which resulted in this error:

```
line 7, in __init__
    self.s.connect(Adress)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I'd like to know where I should go from here to resolve this error and create the connection.

Comment: `I got my real IP by running "curl https://ipinfo.io/ip"` - The IP you got is your IP over internet. The laptop you are trying to connect is over ethernet / intranet. So the local IP should be used. If you have laptops behind a common router the IP's could be something like 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3 etc depending on the subnet config of router.

Comment: I don't think I can just use local IPs because both computers are behind different routers. Sorry for the lack of clarity there, I updated the question accordingly. One laptop is at my house and the other is at my friends. How can I give both the local IP and internet IP so that connection is possible?

Comment: One of you has to configure their router with port forwarding.  The other connects to the public IP and a port, that port is forwarded to the private IP and port on the other side of the router.

Comment: So I assume this is not possible then without port forwarding? and without modifying the router, I can't setup port forwarding?

Comment: You should either use a central server over internet for connecting both clients, and do the exchange of data with some identifier (like a chat server).